# Select by code and if there is no result select any other

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine there are some table with some data:

```
id | code | name
----------------
1  | 0001 | qwer
2  | 0002 | rtyu
3  | 0003 | asdf
```

There can be only one record with `code == 0002`. Also it may be absent.

How could I select record with `code == 0002` and if there is no such record then select any other record with **single query**?

For example for the data example above query returns record with `id == 2`. And for the example below:

```
id | code | name
----------------
1  | 0001 | qwer
2  | 0004 | rtyu
3  | 0003 | asdf
```

any other (one)?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `order by` and limiting the results to one row:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (case when code = '002' then 1 else 2 end)
fetch first 1 row only;
```

This uses Standard SQL.  Not all databases support `fetch first`, so you might need to use `limit` or `select top` or something else.